# Gmail send email API, Authenticate using OAuth2 without storing the refresh token in the app

Tags: node.js, gmail, nestjs, gmail-api, refresh-token

I am sending emails from my NodeJS application which is working fine without any issue (using NestJS framework). The issue I am having is that I need to store the refresh token (in the .env in my case) in order to authenticate which I think is not a good approach. Because, if the refresh token is renewed my app will break and I have to manually update the refresh token every time.
Is there any method to get the refresh token calling any API? any help is appreciated.

following is the code snippet I am using. I have used `nestjs-modules/mailer` but even with `nodemailer` the same issue comes.

```
      transport: {
        service: 'gmail',
        secure: false,
        auth: {
          type: 'OAuth2',
          user: process.env.GOOGLE_SENDER_EMAIL,
          clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT,
          clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
          refreshToken: process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN,
        },
      },
      defaults: {
        from: '"ABC" <abc@gmail.com>',
      },
      template: {
        dir: join(__dirname, 'emails/templates'),
        adapter: new HandlebarsAdapter(),
        options: {
          strict: true,
        },
      },
    }),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you already implementing the [Handling of the Refresh token](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client#handling-refresh-tokens) from the NodeJS library? If so then you could consider using [Domain Wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation) and perform impersonation, this method however will require the usage of a [service account](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7378726) in order to allow the DWD to work.

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer. So using the googleapis library I can generate the refresh token but anyway it needs to be stored in the DB as it is returned only the first time right? It seems that refresh tokens do not expire except it is revoked or passwords are changed. So I think storing the refresh token won't break my app.

Comment: To the question related to the Refresh token, that is correct, it's only retrieved the first time you provide consent, right after that you need to manage the refresh token and store it in your environment so storing it on a DB would work, just consider that the refresh token has an expiration time frame of 7 days depending on how you have configured your app.

Comment: Refresh token expires in 7 days only if the app is in testing state right?

Comment: The documentation is not that clear, however I do know that the expiration date of the refresh token is 7 days by default.